# My HTML form won't post the default values to my sql query unless I manually change at least one item on the form (including an option select)?

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

I have a simple html 5-field (plus 1 dropdown of option words), form where some dollar amounts are entered.  A submit button has an action of a php page that prepares the stmnt to execute, performs a mysql UPDATE, sends me an SMS, etc.

There are default values, zeroes actually, that fill the form to start it out. They're just standard $variables.

The html input fields all have "value"  that is an echoed php variable.

If you do not change at least ONE value (not all 5), there are no affected rows and the UPDATE query fails.

THIS INCLUDES SIMPLY CHANGING THE DROPDOWN ITEM VALUE.

**Not only must a value be changed, but it cannot be cleared and re-entered as the default value.  It must be different.**

The form has a test function that strips characters and such before posting.
The post uses ternary operators to use a 0 if left empty, otherwise use what was entered.

I have tried it removing "required" in the html form.
I have tried removing the ternary operator (since a required input field can't be empty anyway).
I have tried leaving a field empty.

I don't get anything posted to the error log, as it just as affected rows = 0.

The form fields look like this:

```
<form action="proc.php" method="post" >

<fieldset>
<h2>input form</h2>

<b>November: $</b>
            
<input type="number" step="0.01" name="november" size="7" value="<?php echo $nov; ?>" required>
            
<b>December: $</b>
            
<input type="number" step="0.01" name="december" size="7" value="<?php echo $dec; ?>" required>
            
<b>January: $</b>
           
<input type="number" step="0.01" name="january" size="7" value="<?php echo $jan; ?>" required>
           
<b >February:  $</b>
            
<input type="number" step="0.01" name="february" size="7" value="<?php echo $feb; ?>" required>

<b>March: $</b>
             
<input type="number" step="0.01" name="march" size="7" value="<?php echo $mar; ?>" required>
       
<input  id="makechanges" class="makechanges" type="submit"  value="submit" size ="50"  name="submit">
  
</form>
```

This is the action php page that prepares and makes the query.

```
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
} 

 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
  $novpil = test_input($_POST['november']);
  $decpil = test_input($_POST['december']);
  $janpil = test_input($_POST['january']);
  $febpil = test_input($_POST['february']);
  $marpil = test_input($_POST['march']);
  
}

 
 $stmt = $connmember->prepare(" UPDATE smfqg_themes  SET 
                           `value` = CASE `variable`
                            WHEN 'cust_novpil' THEN ?
                            WHEN 'cust_decpil' THEN ?
                            WHEN 'cust_janpil' THEN ?
                            WHEN 'cust_febpil' THEN ?
                            WHEN 'cust_marpil' THEN ?
                            ELSE `value`
                           END
                WHERE id_member = ? ");
  
$stmt->bind_param('sssssi', $novpil, $decpil, $janpil, $febpil, $marpil, $who); 

$stmt->execute();
 

  if  ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
         //echo 'GOOD' ;
        // $greenbar = true;
         sendsms($first, $last, $who);
         header('Refresh: 3; URL=https://example.com/success.php');
     } else {
        echo 'something went wrong, standby:';
        header('Refresh: 3; URL= https://example.com/return.php');
     }
     
     $stmt->close();
     $connmember->close();
     
  }
```

I have echoed the _post values on the action page to see what was brought over, and whether I leave the default values or use my own, they echo fine before the query runs.

I tried ternaries that tested for that default zero to be both a number or string.  I also did a cast (to int and float) for the default values before they got put in the html form, since the default values come from a table as a string (even though just a 0).  No luck.

It would seem that you must either change one field value OR simply change the dropdown to make the form work.   Leaving all untouched won't work.

Comment: Why do you have this `if  ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {` condition at all? What makes you think you need it?

Answer (score -2):

Empty(0) Evals as true, so no change is detected. You will have to either add another condition or use something else than empty()

Comment: Thanks Paul.   I tried using the form "a second time" where I filled in every form with a legit number.   If I just submit the form, it fails even when all the fields are actual values like 4.50, 10.00, etc.   

And, I tried taking the ternary operators out, since the HTML field is required, you have to put 'something' there.    Ideas?

If it's just $novpil = $_POST['November']...wouldn't that take the default HTML value?

Comment: Perhaps $who isn’t a valid user id ?

Comment: No, $who is fine.   It's the form.   All the users have defaults of zeroes in the database---waiting for them to come in and fill it out.    Even if I cursor out a zero, and put a zero back, that doesn't work.   BUT, if I change a single zero to 1 dollar, it works.  AND, if I come back and make THAT 1 a zero again, it works.   But, going forward, if that zero is left a zero....no joy.

Comment: I re-edited the question as the form has a dropdown list of some words.  I presumed the error was variable type related, but you can leave all the zeroes untouched, and if you change the dropdown item to any other word, the form posts fine.

Comment: UPDATE.  Thanks for closing the question and the suggested link.  It wasn't the UPDATE per se, but the affected rows booleans.  I put some conditions in there to test a bad connection, and then if 0 rows ,and then > 0 rows affected.   Works now.  Thank you.